# Example of mutable binary tree in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Using STRef its suppose to be possible to implement mutable data structures. Is there a complete example out there of using STRef to implement a mutable binary tree in Haskell that supports insert, delete, and find operations?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but why do you need your tree to be mutable?

Comment: Mutable is suppose to have more performance. And I'm curious to see what the code would like like.

Comment: Just use an (STRef s (Tree a)) where you would have used a (Tree a) in the type definition of the tree.

Comment: @augustss That's very clear. It almost sounds nice!

Comment: But then all your code using the tree will have to be in ST.  Not so nice.

Comment: @user782220 You can almost always achieve quite good performances with immutable data with some [clever tricks](http://www.amazon.com/Purely-Functional-Structures-Chris-Okasaki/dp/0521663504). I think you'll find mutable anything pretty unpleasant in Haskell.

Comment: @user782220 Using the right data structures, you can get good enough performance for most things. Unless you have a specific need to improve performance in your tree code you should probably skip this for now.